# How can I change my database from sqlite3 to mysql in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've worked with mysql in my django project but in pycharm the default database is SQLite, i've created a MySQL database but I have a database connection problem (**when I run makemigrations and migrate commands, everything runs successfully but the database is still empty**!) so I guess if I could Change db.sqlite3 file to db.mysql maybe I can solve my problem [settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJVw.png) and I don't know if db.sqlite3 file is normal to be like that or that's a problem [db.sqlite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq8Hm.png) but pressing "Reload in another encoding" may change the content of the file [reload in another encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kmn8.png)

Comment: Change your `DATABASES` settings variable

Answer (score 1):

First Enter the Below command in cmd

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Then Change the setting.py file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'django', # database name eg-django
    'USER':'root', # username as root
    'PASSWORD':'', # password keep empty
    'HOST':'localhost', # host is localhost
    'PORT':'3360', # you can find port in xampp control panel(mysql)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Modify the DATABASES parameter in settings.py,like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test2',   # your database name
        'USER': 'root',    # your username
        'PASSWORD': '299521'    # your password
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been resolved.